# How to INSERT INTO access database with c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert-into

I am trying to add data to my access database from winform using c#.

I keep getting a syntax error regarding my INSERT INTO statement and cannot see where I am going wrong.

Please can someone review my code and tell me where I am going wrong.

```
private void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtStatus.Text = "Open";

    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mwool\\Desktop\\Uni\\3rd Year\\SEM 1\\AP\\Assignment\\Staff.accdb";

    string sql = "INSERT INTO Fault (faultType, Status, TechId, StaffId, Zone, Description) VALUES ('" + txtFaultType.Text + "', '" + txtStatus.Text + "', " + txtTechId.Text + "' , '" + txtStaffId.Text + "' , '" + txtZone.Text + "' , '" + txtDescription.Text + "')";

    OleDbCommand add = new OleDbCommand();

    add.CommandText = sql;

    add.Connection = conn;

    add.Connection.Open();

    add.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

}
```

Comment: You're vlnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: You should use prepared statements for that query

Comment: I appreciate there may be flaws in my sql statement, I am a student and this is for my assignment. The program is in early developement. Thanks for the heads up, I will look into resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Always use parameterized queries. This prevents simple mistakes like forgetting a `'` with a string but more importantly prevents sql injection attacks.
- Also always wrap your database connections, commands, and any other Disposable objects in `using` blocks.

Your code refactored with using statements and parameterized inputs.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mwool\\Desktop\\Uni\\3rd Year\\SEM 1\\AP\\Assignment\\Staff.accdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = string sql = "INSERT INTO Fault (faultType, Status, TechId, StaffId, Zone, [Description]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@faultType", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtFaultType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Status", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtStatus.Text;

    // this parameter is an example of passing an int instead of a string. Alwaysuse the correct types!
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TechId", OleDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(txtTechId.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@StaffId", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtStaffId.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Zone", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtZone.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Description", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtDescription.Text;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

OleDbCommand does not support named parameters, see [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ### Remarks
>
> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

---

Also note that:

- OleConnection and OleDbCommand are wrapped in `using` blocks so they are disposed/cleaned up even when an exception occurs.
- Parameters are now used instead of hard coding the string values
- Parameters use the correct data types

It might be that the use of `Description` is not allowed because it is a [reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335) (see link). In that case surround it with `[]` (see update above).

Comment: Thanks for this but it still doesn't work. I am doing something wrong, probably something very basic. Maybe the data types of the fields in my database are incorrect.

Comment: @MWoolley - Could be, I have one example above and mention in it the last note that data types are critical. Check the data types in your table and match those to both the selected `OleDbType` in the `OleDbParameter` as well as make sure that the `txtXXXX.text` value is converted to the correct data type.

Comment: @MWoolley - see TechId as the example parameter.

Comment: @MWoolley - it could be that `Description` is not allowed because it is a reserved word. See my update, using [] would fix it if that is the only issue with what you have at this point.

Comment: thanks I'll have a play with it, try and get the database data types matched up and let you know.

Comment: turns out zone is a reserved word as well. Added [] to that as well and it works! now i'll work on getting it parameterized. Thanks again, this is my first question and was dubious about how useful this approach would be but you've changed my attitude. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MWoolley - good deal, I am glad you got it working! When you have a minute please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Answer (score 4):

You missed a single quote before `txtTechId.Text`. However you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Fault (faultType, Status, TechId, StaffId, Zone, Description) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)";
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtFaultType.Text);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", txtStatus.Text);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", txtTechId.Text);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtStaffId.Text);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtZone.Text);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtDescription.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the single quote but no change, I'll try your other suggestion and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still get the following message:

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: and now this message as well

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: @MWoolley The both version should works if not, you are probably doing something wrong or missed something over here!

Comment: missed [] on description and zone as they are reserved, now I'm going to get the query parameterised. Thanks for your help.